# What is a valid content-type value for a .DM file type ( cellular phone DRM )

Tags: java, mobile, soap, drm

Obeying NDA restrictions I have to be vague.

I've been tasked to evaluate the feasibility of forcing a .dm file from my client's system to a cellular device.  So far I know I can send a smil payload with a txt & gif|jpg payload but not a .dm file.

Inside of the DRM wrapper there is a header prefix before the payload starts.

```
   Content-Type: audio/mpeg
   Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
```

The bridge from our stuff to the cellphone is via a SOAP bridge and what's screwing things up right now is that I have no idea what to tell it I'm sending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this from a quick search, and it recommends using "application/vnd.oma.drm.message".

http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?t=87421

http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?t=51823

Comment: Damn I was looking at the URL this morning, not sure how I missed that

Comment: No problem, sometimes it just takes somebody outside of the problem to look from a different angle. :)

Comment: The information I got there really helped me out by the way, wish I could upvote your answer a 2nd time :)